# Where to locate the Joomla! article item text <p> tag?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Inside Joomla's article template file there is a snippet that will output whatever content that you put inside the article editor:

`<?php echo $this->item->text; ?>`

But where can I find the main file of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code is located on the following file on line **177**:

```
components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php
```

Before you do anything, make sure you create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) if you are considering making any changes. Do not override the core file.

### Update:

To view the source code for the article, simply open the article in the Joomla backend and on the text editor, there should be a small button saying "*html*". This will open a popup containing all the HTML code your your article.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i can locate this variable from that file. But what i meant was that variable has some html tags in it right? I need to know that location. thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, but actually the scenario is i need to put some elements for all succeeding articles so that i won't be needing to put it every time i create an article.

Comment: In which case you should have said before. I would suggest making a Template override for this.